# How to copy ALL photos from a drive to a flash drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, cmd, photos

I want to copy all files of a hard drive to a flash drive, using CMD if possible.

So, create a flash drive with a file on it that backs up your pics WITHOUT re-creating ALL the directories.

I have tried:

```
for /r C:\ %x in (*.jpg *.png *.gif) do @copy /y %x
```

The problem with that, is, a BATCH file doesnt run it, you have to run it directly in CMD.

I have also tried XCOPY and ROBOCOPY, but they re-create the directories, making it very complicated for a user.

Comment: take a look at robocopy on vista+

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use that in a batch file, you just need to double up your `%`'s like this:

```
for /r C:\ %%x in (*.jpg *.png *.gif) do @copy /y "%%x"
```

Note also the double quotes. They are needed in case a name contains spaces and/or other characters that have special meaning in batch syntax, like `+`, `&` etc.

Comment: Thanks Andriy, forgot the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setLocal Enabledelayedexpansion
for %%d in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
    IF EXIST %%d:\nul (
        ECHO %%d
        rem this code will copy all images from whole your pc to a usb labeled as Z or you can change this address(Z:\Private)
        robocopy %%d:\  Z:\private  *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif *.png /S /R:1 /W:1 /NDL /XJD /XD Z:\Private\
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: Please use formatting to make the code more readable and add some explanation to your code-only answer, especially on the purpose of the single letter drive construct. Copying from all drives seems not the answer to OPs question, which refers to a single drive.